# Replace part of string Python

Tags: python, replace

Why is the `.replace()` not working on a pandas dataframe column?

I have this text: `**name: admin-password: *-gid: 80-users: root gwnadmin svc_nessus_osx fviola --**` and I want to replace `*name: admin-password: *-gid: 80-users:*` to `" "`

Here is what I tried so far.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please try to paste text content as text here, try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: In your example, there are more than one spaces after the last `:`, however in your string, there is only one space between `:` and `root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is your string has spaces at the front and the back, you can remove those.
But those are going to only partially match the string, so you'd need to add the regex condition.

```
df['Remarks'] = df['Remarks'].replace('name: admin-password: \*-gid: 80-users: root gwnadmin svc_nessus_osx fviola --', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: I tried this but not worked:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Quales User/Desktop/Juan/upWork/File-Example.csv')
df = df[['Computer Name','Remarks','Status']]
df['Remarks'] = df['Remarks'].replace('name: admin-password: *-gid: 80-users:', '', regex=True)
df`

Comment: Aah yes, as the asterisks is a special characters, it should be \\*. Try the above now.  `replace('name: admin-password: \*-gid: 80-users: root gwnadmin svc_nessus_osx fviola --',`